# Server 2003 can not see xp machines on network

Tags: networking, windows-server-2003, network-share, roaming-profile

I am tesing a few things and one of the things I need to get passed is this problem i`m scartching my head on.

I have server 2003 being used as a terminal server but we are getting rid of that and thats a diffrent problem.

I`ve connected a few xp machines to the domain of the server is all is fine. The problem is on the server under network places I can not see these computers and the computers cant see each other the server.

I can ping and use \ comands but under network places I cant see it. I`m setting up roaming profiles and I want to be able tp drop files and such easily..

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need to 'see' them? start > run > `\\hostname.yourdomain.com\c$` will take you directly to where you need to be.

Comment: Network browsing is an artifact of the past, and home networks.  You really shouldn't be depending on this any more.  These days everything is expected to be done via DNS.

Comment: Sounds like a WINS issue.